# How to have viewable profile pages using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, profile

1. Users need have their own profile pages
2. Plus other users need to be able to view anyone else's profile page
3. I need to be able to link to profile pages in another gem, for example I can click on a post that a user has made (stories gem) and view the poster's profile.

I found a tutorial https://github.com/danweller18/devise/wiki/Allow-Users-to-View-Profile-and-List-All-Users

But this claims to only allow a user to view their own profile. How exactly do I go about to do this (view other's profile)

Comment: I read this tutorial, and i think you can view other people's profile, since there is a user's :id params in the route

Comment: I did it, it allows other people's profiles to be viewed via and address, but it does not tell me how to link to it as a button. How do I do that? Like clicking on a user's posts or listing and view their profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

This is the most common situation, in your routes you need something like this

```
get user/:user_id/profile
```

then on your view you can do something like

```
if current_user.id == params[:user_id]
 # your content when the user is the same
else
 # content for others
```

Also, you can try to do this on the controller and render different content

Answer (score 1):

You can view other people's profile, since there is a user's :id params in the route. To link to a user's profile, use:

```
// using user's name as params
<%= link_to user_path(@user.name) %>
```

Or

```
// using user's id as params
<%= link_to user_path(@user) %>
```